# Pandas. Фильтрация колонок по всем значениям в ней

Tags: python, pandas

Не силен в пандасе, но сделать нужно.

Есть датафрейм с произвольным количеством колонок и строк, в каждой колонке записаны значения от 0 до 10.

Мне нужно оставить только те колонки, в которых ВСЕ значения в ней > 2.
То есть если в колонке даже одно значения будет <= 2, то всю колонку нужно отфильтровать.
Вот как???

При этом нужно учитывать что количество колонок может быть очень большим, так что желательно избегать прямых именований колонок в коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код, который удалит все столбцы, в которых есть числа равные 2 или меньше 2:

```
cols_to_drop = df.columns[df.min() <= 2]
df = df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)
```

df замените на название вашего датафрейма.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать одной строкой с помощью `loc` и булева массива:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.min().gt(2)]
```

Полный пример с генерацией исходного фрейма:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, 100).reshape(10, -1))
print(df)
df = df.loc[:, df.min().gt(2)]
print(df)
```

Результат:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  7  4  7  9  2  3  9  4  3  7
1  2  6  7  8  7  0  2  0  9  5
2  8  3  9  7  9  5  0  4  7  5
3  9  4  9  9  3  0  4  9  3  4
4  9  9  3  1  7  2  9  8  5  2
5  3  6  6  9  3  3  5  0  4  6
6  5  6  9  0  6  0  1  9  2  0
7  5  7  3  6  8  7  2  4  3  7
8  0  3  7  1  1  6  6  9  9  4
9  6  4  8  9  5  6  6  5  2  1
   1  2
0  4  7
1  6  7
2  3  9
3  4  9
4  9  3
5  6  6
6  6  9
7  7  3
8  3  7
9  4  8
```

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже работает, спасибо, к сожалению как верный могу пометить только один =)